# rails button link action controller urlgeneration error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, routes

Two questions. The first is very simple hence it doesn't have its own question

how do I add a css class to the following dynamic rails link:

```
 <%= link_to 'Join Now', { controller: 'home', action:'join'}, {class: 'button'} %>
```

the class is `rest-login` and will the css styles be applied?

now the code I posted above is supposed to replace this code:

```
<button class="rest-login"><h3>Join Now</h3></button>
```

This code:

```
 <%= link_to 'Join Now', { controller: 'home', action:'join'}, {class: 'button'} %>
```

is correctly implemented. As in the controller, the router, and the alike are set up correctly. I even have a link calling the join action that works here it is:

```
 <div class="sign"><%= link_to 'JOIN NOW', join_path %></div>
```

yet this button is working:

```
<%= link_to 'List Space', { controller: 'home', action: 'partner'}, { class: 'button'} %>
```

so this is a hole mess of "what!?!"

Here is the stack trace.

```
Showing /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/charlessite/railssuits/suitsandtables/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #178 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"join", :controller=>"home"}
```

but we go to the controller:

```
def join
  end
```

and the routes.rb

```
get '/join',    to: 'home#clientsignup', as: 'join'
```

and like I said my other links are working.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: A tip - don't tell people "don't edit, don't downvote etc." thats not how the stackoverflow community works. And it will give you downvotes.

Comment: @max Thanks max, but I perfer it my way! Best wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the URI you specify in the route with the controller's action.

If you write `get '/join'`, this `join` is the URI to be used to access your route, and if they point to `home#clientsignup`, then you have a method called `clientsignup` in your `home` controller, but as I see, your method is `join`, so you could try replacing this part, like:

```
get '/join', to: 'home#join', as: 'join'
```

And your `link_to` should work. Although I think you could just use the path, to access your route, if you want to use less code, like:

```
<%= link_to 'List Space', join_path, class: 'button' %>
```

As `join_path` is the alias your route takes, then Rails knows what controller and action it points to, no need to use `controller` and `action` as the link_to's options.

Most probably the other link_to helpers work because they match in the action being specified - I can't say exactly because they're not in the question.

Comment: see I thought the home#clientsignup was pointing to the clientsignup.html file. Hence it was what it was. If I am wrong, then where is the HTML file referenced?

Comment: If `home#clientsignup` points to `clientsignup.html.erb` then `home#join` to `join.html.erb`.

Comment: ok. so then it would seem my initial implementation is correct no? As I still must ref the HTML file? And if my implementation is correct, it still begs the question, for why? lol. why is this still happening.

Comment: Do you have a `clientsignup` method in your home controller? @amazingCarrotSoup.

Comment: That's the reason @amazingCarrotSoup, you're specifying a method that's not in your route. Instead doing as I put in the answer, if you already have your `clientsignup` view, then rename the `join` method to `clientsignup`.

Comment: oh ok let me try and lets see

Comment: rails is so werid I do django, so this is all new to me

Comment: JESUS HELL! it worked thanks man. If I could buy you tacos, I would.

Comment: That's great, tacos will be some day (:

Answer (score 0):

[`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) has several signatures:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
# etc
```

The first is used when you want to use [polymorphic routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```
<%= link_to 'Join Now', { controller: 'home', action:'join'}, {class: 'button'} %>
```

One thing to beware of with polymorpic routing is that it fills missing fields from the current request:

```
<%= link_to 'Join Now', { action:'join' }, {class: 'button'} %>
```

This would link to whatever the controller that was called in the request. Its really best used sparingly when you really need the dynamicism.

In the other case where you are calling `<%= link_to 'JOIN NOW', join_path %>` `join_path` is a route helper method that rails creates dynamically from your routes. It returns a string so its equivilent to:

```
link_to 'JOIN NOW', '/join'
```

If you are using a path helper and want to add options or params to the route you do it by passing the options to the route helper method:

```
link_to 'JOIN NOW', join_path(foo: 'bar'), class: 'button'
```

This would render something like:

```
<a href="/join?foo=bar" class="button">JOIN NOW</a>
```

This example adds a query parameter to the path and `class="btn"` to the link. Passing the controller and action to a route helper is never done since that is already determined. You either call `link_to` with a url or options - not both.

Comment: thanks max appreciate you. Ill take a better look at this answer and post any questions. Appreciate the time your taking.